# Ifelse with a boolean variable resulting in error "ifelse expected at least 3 inputs, a TRUE/FALSE, TRUE/FALSE or command block, and a command block

Tags: if-statement, boolean, netlogo

I'm new to working with Netlogo and am trying to write a scenario where once the turtles reach a certain patch they turn around and return home. I have created a turtle-specific variable to signal whether they have reached the destination (in this case completed the hunt). In order to get them to turn around when and go home when the hunting is done, I am trying to use the ifelse primitive with a boolean, but I keep getting the error listed above.

I know my code is clunky, but I'm quite new at this. Here is the full code:

```
turtles-own
  resources
  hunt-done?
]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-turtles
  setup-patches
  create-route
  create-hazards
  create-hunting-opportunities
  reset-ticks
end


to go
  move-to-destination
  encounter-hazards
  hunt-on-journey
  final-hunt
  encounter-hazards
  hunt-on-journey
  tick
end


;; turtle procedures

to setup-turtles
  create-turtles 4
  ask turtles [
  set shape "person"
  setxy 0 0
  set size 5
  set hunt-done? false
  ]
end

;; turtle procedures

to move-to-destination
  ask turtles [
    ifelse hunt-done? true
    set heading 270
    forward 2
  ][
    set heading 90
    forward 2
  ]
]
end

to hunt-on-journey
  ask turtles [
    if pcolor = green [
      set resources resources + 10 ] ;;adjust number to a probability of hunting success
  ]
end

to final-hunt
  ask patch 327 0 [
    set pcolor violet ]
 ask turtles [
    if pcolor = violet [
      set resources resources + 240
   set hunt-done? true ]
  ]
end

to encounter-hazards
  ask turtles [
    if pcolor = red [
      set resources resources - 20 ] ;; adjust number to a random number to reflect delay and consumption of food
  ]
end

to return-home
  ask turtles [
    if pcolor = violet [
      set heading 270
      forward 2 ]
  ]
end


;; patch procedures


to setup-patches
  ask patches [
    set pcolor grey
  ]
end


to create-route
  ask patches with [ pxcor = 1 AND pycor = 0 ] [
  set pcolor blue ]
  ask patches with [ pxcor > 0 AND pycor = 0 ] [
    set pcolor blue ]
end

to create-hazards
  ask patches with [pcolor = blue] [
    ifelse random 100 < 5 [
      set pcolor red
  ][
    set pcolor blue
  ]
]
end

to create-hunting-opportunities
  ask patches with [pcolor = blue] [
    ifelse random 100 < 10 [
      set pcolor green
    ][
      set pcolor blue
    ]
  ]
end
```

I've also tried using just the if primitive but that also was resulting in an error.

Answer (score 2):

Just two syntax problems in `move-to-destination`.  You are missing an equal sign in your hunt-done test, and a left bracket right after that.

```
to move-to-destination
  ask turtles [
    ifelse hunt-done? = true [
    set heading 270
    forward 2
  ][
    set heading 90
    forward 2
  ]
]
end
```

The equal sign operator makes the comparison of `hunt-done` and `true` yield a true/false, boolean value. But, since hunt-done is already a boolean, true/false variable, you don't need the `= true` at all.  You could just use

```
ifelse hunt-done? [
```

and at run time, as long as `hunt-done` is true or false, NetLogo will evaluate the conditional correctly.  Since you have initialized `hunt-done` to false, you should be all set in that regard.  (Not initializing boolean variables is one of the most common mistakes in NetLogo.)

Comment: Perfect, that fixed it! Thanks for the tip as well about not needing to use an equal sign since its already a boolean.